# put_item() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ConditionExpression'

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to add a conditionexpression while batch write to dynamo db from aws lambda using boto3. But I keep getting this error.

```
 with table.batch_writer(overwrite_by_pkeys=primary_key) as batch:
   for data in array_of_data:
     batch.put_item(
      Item=data,
      ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(partition_key) AND attribute_not_exists(range_key)'
     )
```

data has the key value pair and it works fine without Condition Expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BatchWriteItem (which the batch writer uses) doesn't support conditions. Use put item or update item on the table object directly.